# Set background html image in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I set an image (specified in html) as the background of another div. So far I have this

```
(function ($) {
    var image = $(".filter-content-item").child("img.image-content");
    $(".filter-content-item").css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
})
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this:

```
var image = $(".filter-content-item").child("img.image-content");
```

is obtaining a JQuery obj, not a string of the image's path. You'd have to target the `src` attribute, that has the path to the image:

```
var image = $(".filter-content-item").child("img.image-content").attr("src");
$(".filter-content-item").css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

your **image** is a jQuery Object. So you can use the method **attr()**

```
$(".filter-content-item").css('background-image', 'url(' + image.attr('src') + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers above, you've defined a function but you haven't executed it yet.

Try this:

```
(function ($) {
    var image = $(".filter-content-item").child("img.image-content");
    $(".filter-content-item").css('background-image', 'url(' + image.attr('src') + ')');
})();
```

[This](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) is a good article describing self-executing anonymous functions.